# OAuth Procedure: Request Twice to Server

Tags: security, oauth, server, oauth-2.0, client-server

[image]

I am a beginner to OAuth so my question might sound naive. I found this picture [online](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) describing how OAuth works.

Let's say the client already did the authorization before, which means we already know which authorization the clients get.

So, for the second time when the client request the authorization, I am not sure why can't we **request the authorization** from the client and **return the protected resources** from the server back to the client? So basically we skip steps 2, 3, 4 and 5, and we only keep steps 1 and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you looking at there is the "Authorization Code Grant". This means you have an authentication service that is capable of serving back a login form to the user, authenticates them and then issues a grant. This grant is then turned into an access token via another call.

If you want to do application level authentication then use the Client Credential Grant

This means that you have a ClientID and ClientSecret which identify an application, not a user. You issue a request with those and you get back a token you can use to access a protected resource.

An example is here: https://eidand.com/2015/03/28/authorization-system-with-owin-web-api-json-web-tokens/

If you want to use user credentials for authentication then you can use the Resource Owner Password Credential Grant for example.

So, it all depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know there are so many grant types! So does that mean OAuth is a big topic and it includes Authorization Code Grant, Client Credential Grant, etc?